# Algorithms to matrix multiplications

Tags: c, mpi

I am learning about MPI right now and in the process of developing the cannon's algorithms.

I am trying to write the algorithms such as each process(irank) will takes in a certain part of of the matrix.

For example: 
If my matrix is n-by-n (n=4) and numproc(numproc = 4). There should be 4 blocks each with 4 elements.

Edit: I added a pictures to demonstrates my ideas, each colors represents the data that each processors should receive:

[image]

My question is how would I loop though my small matrix data that it would changes depend on the rank of the process in MPI??

Best,
Andy

Comment: What is "the i and j"?

Comment: I added a images to clarify my question.